# angular test Unexpected request: GET template

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

I trying to test directive, a have `activate()` function, that calls another functions, on error it call `ngDialog.open()`

```
ngDialog.open({
      template: 'path/to/template/error.html',
      className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
      data: data
    });
```

and here is my test:

```
   it('should check activate function', function() {
          $httpBackend.whenGET('path/to/template/error.html').respond(200, '');
          var onActivateSpy = spyOn(scope.$$childTail.headerVm, 'activate'));
    expect(onActivateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

and I have an error:  Error: Unexpected request: GET path/to/template/error.html
what I missed?

**EDITED**
here is my beforeeach:

```
beforeEach(function () {
      module('app');
      module('path/to/template/error.html');
    });
```

and I using ng-html2js preprocessor

Comment: Loading the template as a module seems more suitable to me in this case: module('path/to/template/error.html')

Comment: @DevDig, I'm using this way for compiling directive, and there wasn't problems with it, but when function calls ngDialog, I have error